# Numpy (MKL) Matrix Multiplication doesn't get faster with more CPU Cores

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, intel-mkl

I have a matrix multiplication test to do a `[MxN] * [Nx1]` multiplication. It uses Numpy (and MKL) in Windows:

```
import timeit

import numpy as np
from numpy.random import random_sample

NUMBER_OF_SAMPLES = 1000000
NUMBER_OF_DIMENSIONS = 128

dataset = random_sample((NUMBER_OF_SAMPLES, NUMBER_OF_DIMENSIONS)).astype(np.float32)
feature = random_sample((NUMBER_OF_DIMENSIONS, 1)).astype(np.float32)
print("Finished Generating the Data...")

numbers = 1000
total_time = timeit.timeit('np.dot(dataset, feature)', globals=globals(), number=numbers)
print("Average Time %.3f" % float(total_time / numbers))
```

I benchmarked it on a Core i7 7700 CPU (4 Cores / 8 Threads) and again on a Core i7 7820X (8 Cores / 16 Threads) With HyperThreading disabled and enabled (Disabling Hyperthreading didn't really change the benchmark much):

```
Core i7 7700 (4 Cores) || Data Count 1.000.000 || 128 Dimensional || Time 0.021 s

Core i7 7820X (8 Cores) || Data Count 1.000.000 || 128 Dimensional || Time 0.019 s
```

I expected increasing the CPU count would cut the time by half but it barely did anything.

Is there any way to improve this speed? Thanks.

Comment: Well, you should really be using [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) because you're calling `time()` and also appending to a list in the loop; calls which aren't vectorized and could be taking up a significant portion of the execution time of the loop. But I wouldn't expect the kind of correlation with speed as you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks, Are you telling me that increasing CPU cores shouldn't decrease calculation time that much? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Not quite what I'm saying; there's more to calculation efficiency than just throwing cores at the problem. But your timing method is definitely flawed because it has python calls within the timing loop which will not take advantage of those cores, so you're not really timing `numpy` here. It's `numpy` + some ~constants.

Comment: I changed it to timeit...I even disable the array timing but it had little effect on the efficiency of multiplication. This is really bugging me since I thought MKL could make use of more cores. The funny thing is that with both 8 Core and 4 Cores, the Cores are used 100% of the time but the time doesn't really change that much.

Comment: Matrix-vector products are not great candidates for parallelisation because of the low FLOP count. A matrix-matrix dot product will show far better parallel scalability

Comment: It could be that hyperthreading doesn't help with matrix multiplications at all, I don't know. To check that hypothesis, repeat your test for 1...8 cores with HT enabled and plot the data (with elapsed time * num_cores on the y-axis, num_cores on the x-axis). For perfect parallelization the line would be totally flat, likely it will rise slightly. If HT doesn't help at all, the graph will start flat and rise sharply after core 4. If that's the case adding _real_ CPU cores would help (not just threads). I hear AMD offers some amazing chips for that, at a less insane price than Xeons…

Comment: Your Core i7-7700 has two 256bit broad FMA3 units. That means in this case that one core needs in theory (512/8*3.9*10^9)/10^9=62.4 GB/s, which is more than your RAM is capeable of (intermidiate results and the vector staying in registers and L1-cache). Practically you won't see any speedup with more than two cores. Nevertheless this doesn't explain why your i7 7820X isnt significantly faster. This processor has a quadchannel memory interface and should therefore twice as fast (Maybe it runs only in dual-channel mode?)

Comment: @max9111 You seem to be right. I tried setting the number of cores with `mkl.set_num_threads(x)`. Jumping from one core to two cores shows an effective speedup but switching to 3 and 4 cores doesn't show significant improvements. I haven't checked the Memory Interface yet. I hope someone had access to two 4 and 8 Core setups and could prove if what I'm benchmarking is right or my setup lacks something...

Comment: I benchmarked quite the same thing on a Core i7 4th gen. I also wrote a Numba version of the code (writing out the matrix-vector multiplication in for loops which shows the same results, only a tiny bit faster) But  it would be interesting if someone could benchmark this on a workstation or server which has definitely more than two memory channels. I also have seen this behaiviour many times on other code which runs in a memory bottleneck. But you can also check the speedup by a bigger matrix-matrix multiplication.